# associate iphone application extension like somefile.my.txt

Tags: iphone, file-extension, file-association

In an `iPhone` application I am dealing with files that have a double extension like `*.my.txt`

Thanks to tips found here, I've successfully associated `*.txt` with my app, but am unable to associate `my.txt` with :

```
 <key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
 <array>
  <dict>
   <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
   <string>com.site.my.txt</string>
   <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
   <string>My Text File Type</string>
   <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
   <dict>
    <key>public.filename-extension</key>
    <string>my.txt</string>
    <key>public.mime-type</key>
    <string>application/mytxt</string>
   </dict>
   <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
   <array>
    <string>public.data</string>
   </array>
  </dict>
 </array>
```

I don't have control over the extension unfortunately.
I don't want `*.txt` to open in my app, only those with the extension `*.my.txt`

Would anyone have any tips for me?

Answer (score 1):

By definition, the file extension is everything after the last period in the filename. So the extension of your files is `txt` and not `my.txt`. What you want will not work.